# Pushing local repository to remote repository using python Github

Tags: python, homework, git

The code should do the following in order:

1. It should download/clone the public Github repository locally.
2. It should remove all the git history (and branches)
3. Use the Github API to create a new Github repository initialized with the input github repository content that you downloaded locally. The new repository should be named using name supplied.
   I am able to do steps 1 and 3 but **asks for log-in 2 times**. I am not able to initialize the new remote repo with local repo. **local_repo = repo1** how? And **removing git history?** where can I find git history in the cloned repo.

```
import git,os,tempfile,os,fnmatch,sys
from github import Github

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
input_repo_url = sys.argv[3]
output_repo_name = sys.argv[4]

tempdir=tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="",suffix="")
predictable_filename = "myfile"
saved_umask = os.umask(77)

path = os.path.join(tempdir,predictable_filename)
print("Cloning the repository at "+path)

local_repo = git.Repo.clone_from(input_repo_url,path, branch="master")
print("Clone successful!")

g = Github(username,password)
user = g.get_user()
repo1 = user.create_repo(output_repo_name)
print("New repository created at "+username+" account ")
print(repo1)

target_url = "https://github.com/"+username+"/"+output_repo_name+".git"
print(target_url)

print("Pushing cloned repo to target repo")
local_repo.create_remote("new",url=target_url)
local_repo.git.push("new")
print("Success!!")
```

Comment: I'll happily provide feedback about the script itself, but the larger question is - why? Why would you want to delete all of the history behind a repository when forking a new repo, and why shouldn't a new repo be just that -- a fork?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! . Its a part of an assignment which is supposed to help me understand git and python. So I have to clone a public repo locally, remove history and then push it as a new repository to a remote user's account. How can I use the same git object that i used to create a new remote repo and initialize it with local repo? Because of the 2 objects, 2 log ins are being called.

Answer (score 1):

### Octal permission fields

```
77
```

is likely incorrect. What you've written is 77 in *decimal*, but this would work out to `115` in octal. If you wanted `077` in octal, you would actually need to write `0o077`.

### Pathlib

Consider replacing `os.path` with use of `pathlib`.

### Argument parsing

The `argv` parsing that you've done is fragile - it will fail with an invalid-index exception if the user provides insufficient parameters. Consider using `argparse` instead.

Also: do *not* ask for a password as part of a command line, since it will be stored in the user's shell history. Accept it from an environmental variable, a secure wallet, or from stdin via `getpass` (not `input`).

### String interpolation

```
"https://github.com/"+username+"/"+output_repo_name+".git"
```

is more easily written as

```
f'https://github.com/{username}/{output_repo_name}.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will change them. And what about pushing a local repo to remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

## Comment your code

This is a more general tip, but it is **very** good practice to put comments in your code to make it more readable and understandable